# C : how can I type a name and end it with '.' (dot)

Tags: c

My assignment is to write the last name of a doctor with only small letters and end it with a dot (`'.'`) that the user will print with the output.  The expended assignment is to build a system for medical appointments:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
    fflush(stdin);
    int count = 0, flag = 0;
    char Nameplate;   //last name of the doctor
    printf("Please enter the last name of your doctor(please type with only small letters):\n");
    Nameplate = getchar();
    do{
        Nameplate = getchar();
    } while (Nameplate >= 'a' && Nameplate <= 'z' &&  Nameplate == '.');
    if (!(Nameplate >= 'a' && Nameplate <= 'z' && Nameplate == '.')){
        flag = 1;
    }
    else if (Nameplate == '\n'){
        flag = 0;
        count++;
    }
    if (flag == 1){
        printf("Invalid input,");
        fflush(stdin);
        main();
    }
    else if (flag == 0){
        printf("\n Your appointment has been successfully canceled.\n\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, this code is not working. It is working if I do not use the dot, but when I enter the dot, the problems start.

Comment: Have you read your own question? Do you think it is even readable?

Comment: i'm trying to fix and edit that sorry

Comment: I tried to hammer your Q into shape somewhat, but good god please read [help] and [ask] before asking another question. cc @kaylum

Comment: Your `while` condition is always false. Change the last condition to `Nameplate!='.'`

Comment: edit the condition ` (Nameplate >= 'a' && Nameplate <= 'z' &&  Nameplate == '.'); ` to `while (Nameplate >= 'a' && Nameplate <= 'z'  ||  Nameplate == '.');` and

Comment: sorry again, that was my first post here.. and i tried it its not working.. no matter what i try to change because the "dot" it always give me the flag 1 condition.

Comment: Also, since you're doing a do-while, no need to call `getchar()` before the do-while loop.

Comment: I know this is only an assignment, but that "lower case only" would annoy my friend "Mr O'Doherty", and would *certainly* annoy members of the "De'ath" family in real life (not to mention Mr S. Baron Cohen, and his brother Professor S. Baron-Cohen.)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
while ((Nameplate >= 'a' && Nameplate <= 'z') ||  (Nameplate == '.'))
```

instead of

```
while (Nameplate >= 'a' && Nameplate <= 'z' &&  Nameplate == '.')
```

Comment: You might have noticed that on this site, nobody's code is formatted the way you formatted yours. There's a reason for that.

Comment: I have no idea. I'm a beginner.

Comment: There are hundreds of beginners joining Stackoverflow every day. Read the help, lurk, get familiar with the site _then_ start to contribute. It is much less painful for evevrybody that way.

Answer (score 2):

Even with a change in the test for lower case letters and period, you still have a potential problem because the user might have a period in the name, but still not have a period at the end.

This code checks for lower case letters only, excluding the last character, and then tests that the last character is a period.
Also there is some control on name length.

```
int main()
{
    int flag, n;
    char *Nameplate = malloc(22);   //last name of the doctor
    fflush(stdin);

    while(1) {
        printf("Please enter the last name of your doctor(please type with only small letters):\n");
        printf("End name with a period/full stop\n");
        fgets(Nameplate, 20, stdin);

        /* test for all valid lower case letters */
        flag = 0;
        for(n = 0; n < strlen(Nameplate) - 2; n++) {
           if (!('a' <= Nameplate[n] && Nameplate[n] <= 'z')) {
               /* not a lower case character */
               flag = 1;
               break;
           }
        }

        /* now test for terminating period */
        if(Nameplate[strlen(Nameplate) - 2] != '.') {
            /* no period at end of name */
            flag = 2;
        }

        /* handle errors or accept */
        if(flag == 1) {
            printf("small letters only\n");
        } else if (flag == 2) {
            printf("remember to end with a period/full stop\n");
        } else {
            /* name was all lower case with terminating period so exit input */
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("\n Your appointment with %s has been successfully canceled.\n\n", Nameplate);
    free(Nameplate);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `strlen(Nameplate)-2`?  Surely `-1`?  I think you are thinking of the "trailing nul", but that isn't included in the result returned by strlen anyway.

Comment: @MartinBonner strlen(Nameplate)-2 returns a period at the end of the name entered from stdin terminated by Enter.  I did check that this is where  the ' . '  appears in the string - give it a go yourself just to be sure

Comment: Got it.  It's not the trailing nul, it's the trailing `\n`.

Comment: *Personally*, I would write the test as `!('a' <= Nameplate[n] && Nameplate[n] <= 'z')`.  If all the comparisons are in the same direction, I find them easier to read.  I'd also put a `break` after the `flag = 1`.

Comment: @MartinBonner Yes that is clearer - I will edit the code from the original `(!(Nameplate[n] >= 'a' && Nameplate[n] <= 'z'))` and add the break which will stop unnecessary  comparisons once a non-conforming character is found

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want to enter a doctor's name to set an appointment, only handle lower-case characters, and if the last character is a `'.'` cancel the appointment, you can rearrange your logic slightly and accomplish that goal while still preserving middle-initial punctuation.

Additionally, any time you are taking input, provide a prompt for your user so they are not sitting there looking at a blinking cursor wondering if the program hung.

When handling upper/lower-case conversion, there is no reason to force the user to enter in only one or the other. You can simply check/convert whatever input they provide in a transparent fashion. The `ctype.h` header file holds the `tolower` and `toupper` character conversions, or you can simply understand that the `6th-bit` in `7-bit ASCII` is the case-bit and toggle it as needed to accomplish the case-conversion.

This is just one example, there are many ways to put the pieces together:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 64

int main (void) {

    int c = 0, cnx = 0, i = 0;
    char name[MAXC] = "";

    printf ("\n enter doctor's name (end with '.' to cancel): ");
    while (i + 1 < MAXC && (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
        if (('a' <= c && c <= 'z') || c == '.' || c == ' ')
            name[i++] = c;                      /* add to name        */
        else if ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z')          /* if upper-case      */
            name[i++] = c ^ (1u << 5);          /* convert to lower   */
    if (i && name[i-1] == '.') {                /* last is '.'        */
        cnx = 1;                                /* set cancel flag    */
        name[--i] = 0;                          /* overwrite last '.' */
    }
    else
        name[i] = 0;                            /* nul-terminate name */

    if (cnx)    /* appointment canceled */
        printf ("\n Your appointment with doctor '%s' has been canceled.\n\n",
                name);
    else        /* new appointment      */
        printf ("\n You have a new appointment with doctor '%s'.\n\n", name);

    return 0;
}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/appointment

 enter doctor's name (end with '.' to cancel): John J. Marks

 You have a new appointment with doctor 'john j. marks'.


$ ./bin/appointment

 enter doctor's name (end with '.' to cancel): John J. Marks.

 Your appointment with doctor 'john j. marks' has been canceled.
```